# i can't save UseState get api in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is my output that I get from this GET url: `https://localhost/get-all`
but I can't save this value in the useState:  `const [dataCat, setDataCat] = useState([])`
When I display it in the console, it is displayed correctly, but it returns an empty array in the state

```
{
  "categories": [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "test1",
          "slug": "intelligence-and-memory-tests",
          "description": null,
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "test2",
          "slug": "occupational-and-organizational-tests",
          "description": null,
      },
      {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "test3",
          "slug": "love-and-marriage-tests",
      },
  ]
}
```

this is my useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () =>{
      try {
        const {data} = await axios.get('https://localhost/get-all');
        console.log(data);
        setDataCat(data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    }
  
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: *"but it returns an empty array in the state"* - Where/how are you observing this?  The code shown is setting state, but never does anything with that state.  In the code shown, if `console.log(data)` is producing the correct result, then `setDataCat(data)` is setting that exact result to state.  **Note** however that there is a mismatch in your state *types*.  You are initializing `dataCat` to an *array* but then updating it to an *object*.  Not keeping track of your types could be causing problems elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I guess you need to do `setDataCat(data. categories)` because now you are trying to dump the whole response in the `dataCat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display it like this, and it will store the data in your `useState()`. I've created that `formattedData` to recreate your object

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [dataCat, setDataCat] = useState([]);
  const [newDataCat, setNewDataCat] = useState([]);
  // console.log("dataCat", dataCat);
  // console.log("newDataCat", newDataCat);

  const formattedData = (infoData) => {
    let newDataCat = [];
    infoData.forEach((item) =>
      newDataCat.push({
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        slug: item.slug,
        description: item.description
      })
    );
    return newDataCat;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          "https://localhost/get-all"
        );
        setDataCat(data.categories);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cat = formattedData(dataCat);
    setNewDataCat(cat);
  }, [dataCat]);

  return (
    <>
      {newDataCat &&
        newDataCat.map((item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <h2>{item.id}</h2>
              <h2>{item.name}</h2>
              <h2>{item.slug}</h2>
            </>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank , please remove get address from answer and replace with `https://localhost/get-all` | by the way please tell me why you use this way for store data?
this is best way?

Comment: URL Changed! Well `useState` is used to have state variables in function components, it allows you to keep track of the local state. Using react, to encapsulate the local state, yes I think is the best way.

Comment: @Ariana consider accepting the answer if it helped and you think it could help other people if they have the same problem